# Dual Cone Construction $\{z \; | \;z \perp v \text{ for some } v \in \Lambda \}$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, reference-request, convex-analysis

In a linear algebra computation, in order to estimate the second eigenvalue we consider a collection of vectors.  Let $\Lambda$ be a cone in $\mathbb{R}^d$ then

$$ \Lambda' = \Big\{z \;\Big| \;z \perp v \text{ for some } v \in \Lambda  \Big\}$$

This is also a cone, but which one is it?  The **dual** cone is:

$$ \Lambda^* = \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^d : \langle y, x \rangle \geq 0\;\text{ for all } x \in \Lambda \}$$

I also find a definition of the **polar** cone:

$$ \Lambda^\circ = \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^d : \langle y, x \rangle \leq 0 \;\text{ for all } x \in \Lambda \}$$

---

In order to visualize this cone I stuck to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and considered the vertical line $x = y= 0$.  It is a cone.  And perpendicular to it is the plane $z = 0$.

If we perturb that line to $\Lambda = \{x^2 + y^2 \leq \epsilon z^2 \}$ the other cone $\Lambda' = \{ z^2 \leq \epsilon (x^2 + y^2) \} $.  Hopefully I computed that right.

Visually $\Lambda'$ is osculating the $z = 0$ plane by moving the normal vector to the plane around a small circle.  $\Lambda'$ is connected even if we remove the origin, so it's not like a traditional cone $x^2 + y^2 \leq z^2 $.  The inequality goes the other way.

Comment: You're missing an inequality in your definitions of the cones

Answer (score 1):

Let $\DeclareMathOperator{\in}{int} \in(S)$ denote the (topological) interior of the set $S$.  We have the following result:

> If the cone $\Lambda$ in $X$ is convex, then 
>   $$
> \Lambda' = X \setminus [\in(\Lambda^*) \cup \in(\Lambda^\circ)]
> $$

I'll let you think about the proof.  I don't know if anything nice can be said when $\Lambda$ doesn't have any nice properties.